# Login screen appear after sometime

Tags: 16.04

I am logging into my ubuntu account. But after sometime ( 15-20 sec) the login screen appears and asks to enter the password ( kind of window we get when we start the PC ). Please help me on this error.

Comment: Do you get to see your desktop so you can do things in the 15-20 seconds? If no, it could be that you're login fails as your desktop cannot create temporary work files. If this is the case, you need to switch to a text terminal (ctrl+alt+f4) login, then check disk space (`df -hl`). If you have insufficient space in $HOME (your user directory, or `/home/$USER/`) the login from gui will fail and you get returned to greeter (or login screen).  You need to delete files to create more space in your user directory.

Comment: I am able to view desktop for 15 sec

Comment: The issue does not occur in guest login

Comment: If using Ubuntu-GNOME; a desktop (gnome) extension crashing causes logout - so the extension needs to be disabled (this is usually the result of the extension being for a different GTK+ version than the gnome GTK+ version in use). If it doesn't occur with guest-login (and using Unity), I'd be tempted to create a new user login, ensure it doesn't happen there, then copy the ~/.config/* or  ~/.local/* from the 'new' user overwriting your own (after doing this you'd have to `chown` to your $USER).

Comment: A better approach is probably `diff` (compare) them to your own, to work out wrong config file & just `cp` it from the new user dir to your own dir (with `chown`).  You could also look for clues in logs (`dmesg` etc).  These are vague ideas I know, and may be insufficient to help you (*you were vague in description so I'm guessing rather untechnical*), but I'm not a gnome/unity user, and don't have that environment installed on my system to explore so as to find possible files for you to check.  Maybe another user can provide more specific clues if you need more precise help.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior...